# Import statement was not compiled if it was not used later

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two classes defined in separated files as below.

```
// a.ts
export default class A {
}
```

```
// b.ts
export default class B {
}
```

Below is the code I'm using "a.ts" and "b.ts".

```
// app.ts
import A from "./a";
import B from "./b";
```

After I compiled my source code with `tsc` I found the `import` statements were not emitted to JavaScript file.

```
// app.js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

But if I added some code to use `A` and `B`, they will be emitted.

```
// app.ts
import A from "./a";
import B from "./b";

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
```

```
// app.js
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const a_1 = __importDefault(require("./a"));
const b_1 = __importDefault(require("./b"));
const a = new a_1.default();
const b = new b_1.default();
```

May I change the compilation behaviour so that it will be always emitting the `import` statement regardless if it's used or not.

Below is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by [design](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit), if a module is not used or only types from it are used, it will not be emited. If you want to import a module for the side effects you should do a simple import as suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9191)

```
import "./a";
import "./b";
```